# A marketing report concerning personal computers/Inclusion–Exclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

A marketing report concerning personal computers states
that 650,000 owners will buy a printer for their machines
next year and 1,250,000 will buy at least one software
package. If the report states that 1,450,000 owners will
buy either a printer or at least one software package, how
many will buy both a printer and at least one software
package?

can anyone help me for solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A:\;$ The set of all owners who buy a printer. $\;|A| = 650,00$

$B:\;$ The set of all owners who buy at least one software package. $\;|B| = 1,250,000$

$A \cup B:\;\;$ The set of all owners who buy a printer OR at least one software package. 
$\qquad\qquad|A \cup B| = 1,450,000$

$A \cap B: $ The set of all owners who buy a printer AND at least one software package.

> $$|A\cap B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cup B|$$